# how do I make a progressive line chart for the equation y=2x

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to plot the values of x and y  suing a progressive line chart for my presentation. Any pointer to the right direction or where I can read I will appreciate. So far the closest I have gotten is chart.js here https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/samples/animations/progressive-line.md

sample of expected resyult

[image: 1]

I would like the graph to grow progressively upto a maximum set value of Y as represented by point k

Comment: Please put your code into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Perhaps you could investigate CSS canvas? Updating it every so often. Have a go at coding it and if still stuck put your code into your question, describing what isn't working properly.